# How to get the value of select input in app.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

I want to get the value of option selected in html and call some api, So I have used req.body to do so. But it is giving **undefined** in console.

I have given my html code and app.js code. please figure out the error and give me the right answer.

**HTML code (feedback.ejs)**

```html
<form method="post" id="tableForm" action="/feedback">
<h1>Select input</h1>
  <select class="example" name="example1">
      <option name="" value="0" selected>Select table</option>
      <option name="table1" value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option name="table2" value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option name="table3" value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <select class="example" name="example2">
      <option name="" value="0" selected>Select table</option>
      <option name="table1" value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option name="table2" value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option name="table3" value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**Javascript code (app.js)**

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const { response } = require('express');
const { error } = require('console');



const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get("/feedback", function(req,res){

  console.log(req.body.example1);

  res.render("feedback");
});
  
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a post request to your server that will contain the form input values. For that, you need to add a post route in your server.

**app.js**

```
app.post("/feedback", function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.example1);
    console.log(req.body.example2);
}
```